# Is there a way to emulate HTML/CSS zoom properties in Windows Phone 8 WebBrowser?

Tags: windows-phone-8, browser, zooming, viewport

I want to display a website in a Windows Phone 8 WebBrowser view and fix the viewport zoom to display content in the logical screen resolution, e. g. a 300 CSS pixels wide element should take 300 physicals pixels on a device with a device pixel ratio of 1.0 while taking 600 physical pixels on a hi-res screen with 2.0 device pixel ratio.

Windows Phone 8 WebBrowser view elements rely on @-viewport when it comes to configuring a web page's viewport: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-device-adapt/#the-lsquozoomrsquo-descriptor

Yet, *zoom* properties are not implemented and therefore cannot be used. Is there any CSS or JavaScript approach to achieve the desired behaviour?